# Error CS1525: unexpected symbol 'rigidbody'

Tags: c#

```
public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float forceValue;
    public float jumpValue;
    private Rigidbody rigidbody;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        If (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump") && Mathf.Abs (rigidbody.velocity.y) < 0.01f)
            rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpValue, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"),
                                      0,
                                      Input.GetAxis ("Vertical")) * forceValue);
    }


}
```

When I compile this code. I get:

> Move.cs(19,3); Error CS1525: unexpected symbol 'rigidbody'.

Why is it happening and how to fix it?

Comment: come up with code instead for screen shot

Comment: could be the capital I in If

Comment: My first post. I couldn't expect any good comment. Thanks.

Comment: Well, just read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question appropriately. We´re happy to retract all our votes, if your question is well formed and shows some affords.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and the suggestions about my post. I learned a lot. The problem was the if

Comment: Well, although OP has a question and is happy with it, I doubt this is very helpfull for future readers, as it´s a simple typo.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Indeed, but seems I'm the only one who has VTC for that reason so far :/

Comment: @DavidG I had a vote for missing code, which is why I can´t cast a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# is case sensitive. Because of the typo `If` (instead of `if`), the compiler thinks `If` is a method name. Hence, after the closing parenthesis of the `If` method call, it expects a semicolon for example, not a statement.

That is why you get the little obscure error.

This is the working code:

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump") && Mathf.Abs (rigidbody.velocity.y) < 0.01f)
    rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpValue, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it complain about the name `If` not existing in the current context?

Comment: It probably does @DavidG

Comment: Throwing the code into my window doesn't say anything about `rigidbody` not being valid though.

Comment: It isn't invalid, it is just unexpected.

Comment: Yes, but the only errors I see are `; expected` and `The name 'If' does not exist...`

Comment: Maybe another version of the compiler? @DavidG

Comment: Hmm maybe, looks like Unity.  Either way, question needs to be closed as typo.